# Polymer 2 events

Tags: polymer, shadow-dom, polymer-2.x, custom-element

I am rewriting my `Polymer 1.0` application to `Polymer 2.0` (and TS) and I encountered a problem. How to transfer an event from one element to another? I used an `iron-signal` earlier, now I'm trying to use the `CustomEvent`, but because of the `ShadowDOM` event does not reach the element.

The hierarchy of elements is approximately the following:

`1 {2 {3 {4}}}}`.

I need to throw an event from `element 1` to `element 4`, and in another case, vice versa.

How can I do that? Only through `window.AddEventListener`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, custom events stop at shadow DOM boundaries. To make a custom event pass through shadow DOM boundaries, set the **composed** flag to true when you create the event:

```
var event = new CustomEvent('my-event', {bubbles: true, composed: true});
```

https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/events

Comment: And I should listen to this event like this:
  window.addEventListener ('my-event', function() { ... }) ?

Comment: Specifically look at https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/events#imperative-listeners so that the custom event is added and removed correctly.